# Desiarlize date object Newton Json

Tags: json, json.net

I've tried several different string formats and json serializer settings but can not come up with the right combination; my date always comes out as the default min date value.

I'm doing:

```
_flashMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlashMessage>(msoSite.FlashMessage, settings);
```

Where FlashMessage is:

```
public class FlashMessage
{
    public string Device { get; set; }
    DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public List<string> Message { get; set; }
}
```

And my Json string is:

```
{
  "Device": "Mobile",
  "Expires": "2015-03-13T11:35:35",
  "Message": [
    "This is a test message..."
  ]
```

}

The date result I'm getting is:

[image]

Comment: Not true.  It is working fine now.  I just made a silly mistake when defining my class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:  my DateTime Expires property wasn't defined as public, therefore out of scope and not getting set.